# New columns from all possible combinations of columns of a data frame

Tags: r

I want all of the possible combinations, grouping by 2 some columns in a data frame, without repetitions (the order does not matter). I want to append the new column having the name of the two joining columns.
example:

```
df
col1  col2 col3 col4 
ind1    a    c    a    
ind2    c    g    a    
ind3    a    g    t
```

And I want to get:

```
newdf
col1  col2  col3  col4  col2col3  col2col4  col3col4
ind1    a    c    a         ac       aa        ca 
ind2    c    g    a         cg       ca        ga
ind3    a    g    t         ag       at        gt
```

I have tried the following:

```
cl <- c("col2", "col3", "col4") #vector with the columns I want
library(gtools)
lg <- length(cl) 
cmb <- combinations(lg, 2, cl) #this gives me all the combinations without repetition
cmb
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "col2" "col3"
[2,] "col2" "col4"
[3,] "col3" "col4"
cmb <- paste(cmb[,1],cmb[,2]) #for joining the columns of cmb
cmb1 <- paste0("df$",cmb[,1], ", df$", cmb[,2])
```

After this I tried to use `sapply`  but I´m not able to make it work. This is one of many tries.

```
newdf <- sapply(cmb1, function(x) {
         df$[,x] <- paste0(x)
         })
```

Is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Well, it looks like you're missing a parenthesis . . . but what error statement are you getting? What's the output you're looking for?

Comment: I want to get the table newdf. I have corrected the parentheses thing, but that was not the problem. I got a lot of different errors, in this case seams to be a problem with "," somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `mapply()` over a predefined list of the columns. First you need to create the matrix of the columns names, like you did. You can also use `comb()` to do it:

```
> df <- data.frame(col2 = c("a", "c", "a"), col3 = c("c", "g", "g"), col4 = c("a", "a", "t"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> nombres <- combn(colnames(df), 2)
> nombres
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
[1,] "col2" "col2" "col3"
[2,] "col3" "col4" "col4"
```

Then, you create two list of vectors:

```
> lista1 <- lapply(nombres[1,], function(x){
+   df[,x]
+ })
> 
> lista2 <- lapply(nombres[2,], function(x){
+   df[,x]
+ })
> lista1
[[1]]
[1] "a" "c" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c" "a"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "g" "g"

> lista2
[[1]]
[1] "c" "g" "g"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "a" "t"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "a" "t"
```

Finally, use `mapply()`, and `paste()` the two lists:

```
> mapply(function(x, y){
+   paste(x, y, sep = "")
+ }, x = lista1, y = lista2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "ac" "aa" "ca"
[2,] "cg" "ca" "ga"
[3,] "ag" "at" "gt"
```

Then you can `cbind` the matrix to the original dataframe:

```
> df2 <- mapply(function(x, y){
+   paste(x, y, sep = "")
+ }, x = lista1, y = lista2)
> 
> colnames(df2) <- paste(nombres[1,], nombres[2,], sep = "")
> 
> df_new <- cbind.data.frame(df, df2)
> df_new
  col2 col3 col4 col2col3 col2col4 col3col4
1    a    c    a       ac       aa       ca
2    c    g    a       cg       ca       ga
3    a    g    t       ag       at       gt
```

Hope it helps!